# Softlayer API: To order BM or Order Upchagre are failing with "Read Time Out"

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Softlayer API to order BM or Upcharg are failing with *"Read Time Out"* error.

> "SoftLayer.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(0):
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.service.softlayer.com', port=443): Read
>   timed out.

Is there a way to avoid the error or increase the "timeout" on our end?

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can try to increase the tiemout and see if the issue goes away, but that depends on what client your are suing for example for the Softlayer's python client this is the way to increae the timeout:

```
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username='YOUR_USERNAME',
                                          api_key='YOUR_API_KEY'
                                          endpoint_url=SoftLayer.API_PRIVATE_ENDPOINT,
                                          timeout=240)
```

You just need to set that value at the moment to create the client.

Nw for other clients it may different how to increate the timeout. As I said the timeout is a configuration related to the client that you are using.

Regards